# How can I tell if my script is being run in elevated mode?

Tags: cygwin, elevation

This is mainly to change the prompt for elevated shells in Cygwin.

I need to know a fast command of either Windows or Cygwin that tells me whether i'm elevated in Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](http://cygwin.1069669.n5.nabble.com/Question-about-UAC-and-bash-cygwin-tp91982p92035.html) it's done with the help of Cygwin's command `id`:

```
id -G | egrep -q '\<544\>' && set prompt = '#  || set prompt = '\$ '
```

Or in my case with `bash` i added this to the end of `/etc/bash.bashrc` (Note that I removed the `\n` that comes in default prompt):

```
id -G | egrep -q '\<544\>' &&
 PS1='\[\e]0;\w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]# ' ||
 PS1='\[\e]0;\w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\$ '
```